# How do I forward messages posted on different server to mine using discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a bot on my server, I just need some kind of direction on how to do it or if its even possible.

The bot function is to copy the message that's being posted in different server and post it into my own server. Bare in mind that the bot is only on my server.

The code below forwards the message from text channel to another text channel in my own server. The main objective is to  forward a message from different server into mine.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'ODA3MjAyOD456ODE3NzU2Njcz.4GFDFHA.8MHQ9ZaGSFFFEDSJZQSgv-wB84'; //fake token

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith('*'))
    return;

  if (message.content === '*pp') {
    let channel = client.channels.cache.get('80565937858574763'); // gets the message from this channel

    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => { 
        let lastMessage = channel.lastMessage.content;
        const marketnews = client.channels.cache.get('807577438839489436096'); //sends it to this text channel
        marketnews.send(lastMessage);
    })
  }

});
client.login(token);
```

Disclaimer: Channel ID and Token are examples and not real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its pretty easy, if message guild id is not your server id then it will send that message with information to your server text channel.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => { //Message Event
   if (message.guild.id != "YOUR GUILD ID") { //If Guild ID Is Not Your Guild ID
     const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("GUILD LOG MESSAGE CHANNEL ID"); //Finding Log Channel With ID
     if (!Channel) return console.log("No Channel Found To Log!"); //If No Channel
     const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //New Embed
     .setColor("RANDOM") //Setting Color
     .setTitle("New Message") //Setting Title
     .setDescription(`Author - ${message.author.username} (${message.author.id})\nGuild - ${message.guild.name} (${message.guild.id})\nMessage -\n${message.content}`) //Description
     .setTimestamp(); //Timestamp
     return Channel.send(Embed); //Sending Embed To Channel
  };
});
```

Links:
[Guild#id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id)
[MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm starting to get it, took a while. If I don't want it to be embedded and just have text, I'm guessing message.content is fine?

Comment: Still having problems with guild ID and "Guild Log message channel ID"

Comment: Hey, so the code works but unfortunately, you need to have the bot both channels to be able to do it, I just wanted only my channel to include the bot but its okay its all good. I appreciate the help. Thank you for all the help :)

Comment: what do you mean by both channels? you just have to put your guild id (so it will not send  messages to your guild) & channel id where you want to log other servers channels messages, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. What I meant was the bot needs to be in both of the servers. I wanted is to copy messages posted in another server and post it to mine but it involves having the discord bot in both of the server. I only wanted the bot in my channel only. Thanks

Comment: ohhh i see sorry

Comment: All good, the code is still useful and appreciate the help :)